# Delete all transactions from sandbox account

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-sandbox

Here's my problem. When I create my transaction with the classic api, I find myself giving them a unique tracking id (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) that match the one I store in my DB.

But after 8 months of devellopement, I have some problem. I reset my DB, so on my end, the tracking id can be used, but on Paypal end, it can't.

So I was wondering if there's any way to delete the transactions I've made so far? That way I could re-use theses tracking ID and make sure that this time I don't delete the one I've used, but instead store them in another collection.

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

What I finally did was to make a simple function that generate another ID if the id was refuse by paypal, and add the refused one in my DB. That way, at some point, I caught up with the paypal transactions ids and was good to go!

Answer (score 0):

What we did was to just create another app in our Paypal developer dashboard.